# Pagination on result by running sql on View in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

There are three tables in database. Using these tables, need to show details from these tables in grid/table format on page.

To fetch the details from three tables, I created one view in database.
But the issue is how can I implement sorting and pagination on view?

Is any solution for this? For existing grids on pages I used will_paginate

Answer (score 0):

A view responds to SELECT queries like a normal table (and possibly to updates, etc. depending on your database server - [example MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-updatability.html). You should be able to use the standard approach: write a model for that view and a controller for that model

Ryan Bates Railscast website holds an episode on [Sortable Table Columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?view=asciicast). The tutorial is a bit outdated but the general idea still applies. You can use will_paginate when you read the objects.

Comment: Any idea about the performance impact of adding pagination to a view? Because a view is no more than a stored procedure? So I imagine if you have a view with e.g. a million records and select with paging only 10 of them, you would still need to calculate the view with a million records... ?

Comment: Performance should be similar to the performnce of the query which defines the view. Should also very much apply to pagination (achieved through OFFSET and LIMIT on the view). 
A view is a cached query, the DDL defining a virtual table, not a stored procedure. Some database servers implement materialised (persisted) views. A view uses the same optimisations as the defining query. Good indexes will not require a full scan of the data when you pick 10 from anywhere. 
A thread discussing performance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529259/do-database-views-affect-query-performance