# Java Spring Boot performance issues with JPA @OneToMany LAZY relation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have some `DepartmentView` which has **@OneToMany** relation with another view `UserDepartmentView` and my problem is when I'm trying to load all *departments* it takes too much time.

It takes about **4s to load 600 entries** locally and on production environment even more time

I tried to use **@EntityGraph** implementation but it didn't really help me to decrease load time.

Any idea how I can optimize the code to improve the load time ?

P.S. the `DepartmentView` has much more other propeties which I just not listed in the code snippet

```java
public List<DepartmentDTO> getDepartments() {
    Specification<DepartmentView> specification = getSomeSpecification();

    List<DepartmentView> departmentViews = departmentViewRepo.findAll(specification);

    return departmentViews
        .stream()
        .map(DepartmentDTO::new)
        .toList();
}

public interface DepartmentViewRepository extends CrudRepository<DepartmentView, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DepartmentView> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"users"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<DepartmentView> findAll(Specification<DepartmentView> specification);
}

@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "department_view")
public class DepartmentView implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "department_id")
    private String departmentId;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<UserDepartmentView> users;
}


@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "user_department_view")
public class UserDepartmentView {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_department_id", referencedColumnName = "department_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    @ToString.Exclude
    private DepartmentView department;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class DepartmentDTO {
    private String id;
    private String departmentId;
    private String name;
    private List<UserDTO> users;

    public DepartmentDTO(DepartmentView departmentView) {
        this.setId(departmentView.getId());
        this.setDepartmentId(departmentView.getRequirementId());
        this.setName(departmentView.getName());
        this.setDataUsers(getUsers(departmentView));
    }

    private static List<UserDTO> getUsers(DepartmentView departmentView) {
        return departmentView.getUsers()
            .stream()
            .map(UserDTO::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with FetchType.EAGER. This will give u all data at the calling of query.

Answer (score 3):

As @Avinash Verma says eager can help you with the performance problem. Another thing you should think about is your data model and the way how you are getting the data from DB. From my experiences OneToMany relation should not be used when possible. In most cases every OneToMany can be designed using ManyToOne when you are looking on the relationship from the opposite side.

In your example if you have department entity and user entity. One department can have many users so there is one to many relation in department entity. User can belong to only one department so there is many to one relation in user entity. So if you want to get all users for one department just go through user entity. It is better to just make

```sql
select * from User where department = ?
```

then select them through department table which one to many is doing that.

Another way is to create relation table between user and department for example user_department. Then you will have an entity named f.e. UserDepartmentRelation where you will have two manyToOne relationships (one to user and one to department). So you can use this relation entity to get users of one department and just map somehow data from relation entity to your dto object. This relation table and entity is usually used for ManyToMany relation but could be used also for that case.

Another thing what I can see it looks like like you are using view in database. Views are usually slower than just make a select with join. Also you can use column indexing mechanism which can also help you to eliminate performance problem.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, actually even before implementing part with users the loading time for all departments was still too long, is it because a view right ? I just doing a "findAll" with some specification and that's it

Comment: It is hard to say to be honest. It depends on the complexity of the view itself and also amount of data in the table can affect performance. You can check discussion about view performance here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529259/do-database-views-affect-query-performance . You can try to select data directly from the table (you can do it using JPA) not from the view and you will see the difference. Also as I mentioned you can add some indexes to columns you are using for querying data. But be careful indexes can also affect performance of the database.