# Does MySQL have an equivalent of SQL Server "indexed views"?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, materialized-views, indexed-view

Does MySQL have an equalavent to SQL Servers "indexed view" functionality?

[Is a view faster than a simple query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query)

What I'm specifically looking for is a way for MySQL to create a "view" that will return results faster than simply performing the underline view's query/sql.

Answer (score 3):

An Indexed View is SQL Server terminology for a materialized view, which MySQL does not support.

You can either:

- re-create a temporary table, populated with the desired columns, at a given interval
- use an actual table, populated and indexed though again - there'd have to be a process to keep the data and indexes current

Comment: While considered a silver bullet, materialized views are notoriously constrained on any vendor.  You can't use non-deterministic functions IE: SYSDATE or GETDATE, among other things.