# Is create a Table for reporting faster than create a View for reporting?

Tags: sql, hibernate

Is this possible when I want to create a View for report by SQL Query. This View have some column is calculated from another column in some different tables. I saw my friend in my college did not use View, they just created a new table to store that report. They said it would make their application run faster than create a View when data become bigger. Is this right and any suggest for me ? And Is It possible using Hibernate to get result from View ?

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query?rq=1

Comment: I don't think that link is related to the OP question...

Comment: Creating redundant data per report is a flawed design. However, as for performance, if you're doing all the joins and other calculations beforehand and storing it away in a separate table, you will get better perf. I would NOT do it this way, instead, learn to index properly. Or look into materialized view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As off now i do not have the complete step by step tutorial with me but the following hibernate view code will help you to solve your problem

I am using HIBERNATE+JPA annotation

VIEW Name : - VIEW_SAMPLE

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;




@Entity(name = "VIEW_SAMPLE")
public class ComplianceNonComplianceFrontEndView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -689896943115399462L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMPANYCODE")
    private String companyCode; 

    @Column(name = "COMPANYNAME")
    private String companyName;


    @Column(name = "MANAGER_NAME")
    private String manager;



    public String getCompanyCode() {
        return companyCode;
    }

    public void setCompanyCode(String companyCode) {
        this.companyCode = companyCode;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(String manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }



}
```

Hibernate Code to get the result from the view

```
public ComplianceNonComplianceView getCNCViewByCompanyCode(String companyCode) {
        String query = null;
        ComplianceNonComplianceView cncView = null;
        try{

            query = " select cncvw from com.crose.rats.bd.transactions.model.ComplianceNonComplianceView cncvw "+   
                    " where "+
                    " cncvw.companyCode = :clientCode " ;

            cncView = (ComplianceNonComplianceView)this.em.createQuery(query).setParameter("clientCode", companyCode).getSingleResult();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("===============  Exception Occured in  : -getCNCViewByCompanyCode() ");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cncView;
    }
```

Let us know if you have more query. Or post your code so that it will be more use full

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding your question :** Is It possible using Hibernate to get result from View ?

Yes you can user hibernate to get the result from the view.

**Why we should use view : -** If in your application you want to show report or DB VIEW to some other person who shouldn't be able to modify your data than i would go for view creation.

**Performance of VIEW : -** It depends how much data you are  fetching from the different tables, calculations your are performing while creating the view. If you apply more joins, more calculations on data your performance will suffer.

**Recommendation : -** If you have large data, more tables and want to performence cumbersome logics on the data than i would go for materialized view which are quite fast and responsive. So it all depends how your application is

Comment: Can you send to me a clear tutorial about getting result from View ?

Comment: I have posted a sample code for your which comprises of view for which i have created POJO alongwith the anotation and the hibernate query to  fetch the results from the view.