# Best way to load high number of records in grid view

Tags: asp.net

Apart from the gridview pagination, stored procedure pagination and the on scroll loading of the records in a grid view, what are the other best ways to load a 10000+ records on a view.

Comment: Just ignore GridView. use a lightweight alternative with least inline attributes and formatting

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see besides gridview/SP pagination is creating a View for the select you're executing, because they are faster than simple queries or SPs.

Take a look at: [Is a view faster than a simple query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query)